# Python - print tab delimited two-word set

Tags: python

I have a set of words such as this:

```
mike dc car dc george dc jerry dc
```

Each word, `mike dc george dc` is separated by a space. How can I create a two-word set and separate the two-word set by a tab? I would like to print it to the standard output `stdout`.

**EDIT**
I tried using this:
`print '\t'.join(hypoth)`, but it doesn't really cut it. All the words here are just tab delimited. I would ideally like the first two words separated by a space and each two word-set tab delimited.

Comment: What _is_ the output of `print '\t'.join(hypoth)`?  What is `hypoth`?

Comment: The output of that command is `mike   dc   car   dc   george   dc   jerry   dc`. The words are all tab delimited

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have

```
two_word_sets = ["mike dc", "car dc", "george dc", "jerry dc"]
```

use

```
print "\t".join(two_word_sets)
```

or, for Python 3:

```
print("\t".join(two_word_sets))
```

to print the tab-separated list to stdout.

If you only have

```
mystr = "mike dc car dc george dc jerry dc"
```

you can calculate a as follows:

```
words = mystr.split()
two_word_sets = [" ".join(tup) for tup in zip(words[::2], words[1::2])]
```

This might look a bit complicated, but note that `zip(a_proto[::2], a_proto[1::2])` is just `[('mike', 'dc'), ('car', 'dc'), ('george', 'dc'), ('jerry', 'dc')]`. The rest of the list comprehension joins these together with a space.

Note that for very long lists/input strings you would use [`izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) from [`itertools`], because `zip` actually creates a list of tuples whereas `izip` returns a generator.

Comment: The words are not in a set. They are a string and I would like to split each consecutive two-word set by a tab. Maybe I wasn't clear in my question. How do I accomplish what I want to do by doing that?

Comment: @Eagle I'll add that, but please be more specific in your question next time ;-)

Comment: @Eagle I added a solution for your splitting problem. Please review if this is what you asked for

Comment: Excellent! I did not think of using the zip() function for this. The function truly has many uses! Thank you! :)

Comment: @Eagle No problem. My  solution is essentially the one-line-version of Kevins answer below!

Comment: @Eagle FYI, If you have a really large list, `izip` from `itertools` might be better that `zip` which actually creates a list of tuples.

Comment: @Eagle I think it will be sufficient to `import itertools` and then just substitute `zip` with `izip`. If it is worth the effort, depends on your usecase ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in 1-2 lines, but it is easiest to read if you break it up:

```
words = "mike dc car dc george dc jerry dc"
wlist = words.split()
mystr = ""
for i in range(0, len(wlist), 2):
    mystr = "%s%s %s\t" % (mystr, wlist[i], wlist[i+1])
print mystr
```